# How do I find what is common between 2 lists?

Tags: javascript, python

I have 2 long lists of chemicals (approx. 100 chemicals each) and would like to find which chemical are common in both lists. I basically need a program that will allow me to insert 2 long lists and then print out the chemicals that are common. I currently only know java-script and python and am not sure how to do this without going through every chemical in at least 1 of the 2 list.

Comment: what you tried already ?

Comment: I have inserted one list into the script and then inputted the chemicals from the other list to see if the chemical that I inputted is in the list that is in the script.

Comment: You should be posting what you've tried not asking for code

Answer (score 1):

You can try underscore.js for variety of operations in **JavaScript**.
`_.difference :` Returns the values from array that are not present in the other arrays.

```
_.difference([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [5, 2, 10]);
=> [1, 3, 4]
```

You can try it in **python** like

```
list(set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) - set([5, 2, 10]))
=> [1, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

In JS you can do something like this using [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
var arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var arr2 = [3, 10, 12, 4, 15];

function findCommon(arr1, arr2) {
    return arr1.filter(function (el) {
        return arr2.indexOf(el) > -1;
    });
}

findCommon(arr1, arr2); // [3, 4]
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kthyyhds/)

Answer (score 0):

You could use sets to do this. I would though recommend converting each entry to lowercase first though as follows:

```
list_1 = ["Barrelene", "Mimimycin"]
list_2 = ["Prismane", "barrelene", "Josiphos"]

set_1 = set([x.lower() for x in list_1])
set_2 = set([x.lower() for x in list_2])

print set_1.intersection(set_2)
```

This would display:

```
set(['barrelene'])
```

If the two lists are in text files, you could use the following script:

```
with open('list_1.txt', 'r') as f_list_1:
    set_1 = set([name.strip().lower() for name in f_list_1])

with open('list_2.txt', 'r') as f_list_2:
    set_2 = set([name.strip().lower() for name in f_list_2])

for name in set_1.intersection(set_2):
    print name
```

I would suggest you use Microsoft Word to save your two documents as a text file. It is though also possible to use a Python module to read the `docx` file directly.

Comment: Does that mean that I have to put quotation marks around every single chemical?

Comment: Where are your lists?  Are they in two text files, i.e. one name per line?

Comment: They are like that in a word document.

Comment: I have added a version that can work via text files. Word files would need another library.

Answer (score 0):

l1 = [1,2,3,4]

l2 = [3,2,22]

commonInBoth = set(l1) & set(l2)

print(commonInBoth)

**{2, 3}**